# Servlet Mapping is not working correctly

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I am new to spring mvc and these are the errors I got:

```html
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml]
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
 ... 28 more

May 27, 2017 1:13:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml]
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
 ... 28 more

May 27, 2017 1:13:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [spring-mvc] in web application [/TooO] threw load() exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml]
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And my web.xml:

```html
  
  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
 <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/servlets/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

My spring-mvc-servlet.xml is located in WEB-INF/servlets/spring-mvc-servlet.xml

I dont know what exactly the url-pattern is looking for. for the path of the url-pattern, what would it be? For example, in my case, what would the url-pattern print out? is it WEB-INF/servlets/?

Comment: Move your spring-mvc-servlet.xml directly into WEB-INF and restart...

Comment: Yeah that one was working but I wanna my servlet be in the servlet folder, would it be done successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your config file.

See eror message

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
     Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml]
```

But you have it in `WEB-INF/servlets/spring-mvc-servlet.xml` as you say

Move it to WEB-INF directory and restart - you should at least see new error messages

To your "real" question:

If you're using spring, you don't create servlets - you create controllers. The path given in each Controllers mapping will then be prepended by the URL mapping given to Spring Servlet.

So an URL like http://yourserver:8080/yourapp/servlet/doSomething

Would resolve like this:

yourapp -> Tells the *Servlet Container* to target your application
   servlet -> Tells Spring that this is meant for Spring
   doSomething -> will peform a lookup in all Spring Controllers if some of them match that URL pattern (inside Spring config!)

This is totally independend of where you put your class-files - and the class files for this would have to reside in WEB-INF/classes (or inside jars in WEB-INF/libs)

Good Luck

Comment: I know this would work. But I want my servlet xml files inside of the servlets fold, can it be done in any way?

Comment: see my edit - but your question is totally asking something different - and the errors as well :-)